# How to get git commit hash in Jenkins declarative pipeline if checkout scm fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins declarative pipeline, with option `{ skipDefaultCheckout() }`, is there a way to get the git commit that Jenkins is trying to check out before even calling `checkout scm`?

I can see env variable:
`BRANCH_NAME` but not commit

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
repoUrl = 'ssh://git@repo.addr/repo.git'
node {
    branchHash = sh(
        script: "echo -n \$( git ls-remote ${repoUrl} refs/heads/${env.BRANCH_NAME} | cut -f1 )",
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
}

pipeline {}
```

Comment: this is not declarative pipeline

Comment: no, it's not. This is a work-around to use the defined variable within the declarative pipeline that is going to be defined in the last line.